# Is there a way to make sure a background process listens to a simulated keystroke from an apple script?

Tags: bash, applescript

I'm trying to write a bash script to create a new desktop, then open a program, and then automatically move it and resize it to the top left corner of my Mac.

So far I'm able to get the first 2 parts working, but I can't get the windows to resize properly.

I created a keyboard shortcut on BetterTouchTool to listen for "1 + command + option + control". This shortcut automatically moves the current window to the top-left corner of my screen. When I open this program and press these commands manually it works like a charm, but when I try to simulate these keystrokes from a script BetterTouchTool doesn't notice they were pressed. I'm guessing that BetterTouchTool must have a background process that's always listening for user input, but when this input is simulated or not directed to the right place that process doesn't notice it. Is there a way to fix that?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

app1="Zotero"

# Create a new desktop
osascript <<END
tell application "System Events"
  do shell script quoted form of "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
  click button 1 of group "Spaces Bar" of group 1 of group "Mission Control" of process "Dock"
  do shell script quoted form of "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
end tell
END

# Wait for Mission Control to open and switch to the new desktop
sleep 1
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down' # Press Control+→ to switch to the new desktop

# Launch application 
open -a "$app1"
sleep 3 # Increase sleep time to allow the application to fully load

# Set the position of the application window
set_window_position() {
  local app_name=$1
  local position=$2
  osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"$app_name\"
    try
        log \"Setting $app_name to the forefront\"
        set frontmost to true
        log \"Frontmost successfully set to tru for $app_name\"
        delay 0.5
        log \"Sending keystroke: $position + control + option + command\ to move window\"
        keystroke \"$position\" using {control down, option down, command down}
        log \"Keystroke successfully sent\"
   on error errMsg
        log \"Error setting window position for $app_name: \" & errMsg
   end try
end tell"
  sleep 1
}

set_window_position "$app1" "1" # Move Zotero window to top-left
```

Can this bash/applescript be modified to work?

Comment: Seem you [could tell BTT](https://docs.folivora.ai/docs/1102_apple_script.html) to trigger an action instead of telling 'System Events'  to press a key.